# Angular2 unit tests causing a race condition

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, race-condition

I'm testing whether a componment's UI fields are correctly updated by the input field.  I'm suffering a race condition where the results of one test are being compared to the expectations of another test.

My unit test code:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EntityEditorComponent, EntityEditorModule } from '.';
import { Entity, EntityType } from '..';

describe('EntityEditorComponent template', () => {
  let target: EntityEditorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EntityEditorComponent>;
  let nameElement: HTMLInputElement;
  let typeElement: HTMLSelectElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [ EntityEditorModule ] }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntityEditorComponent);
    target = fixture.componentInstance;
    nameElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    typeElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#type')).nativeElement as HTMLSelectElement;
  });

  [
    { expectation: 'null', name: null       , expected: null        },
    { expectation: 'set' , name: 'Unit Test', expected: 'Unit Test' },
  ].forEach((test, i, tests) => {
    it('#name displays Entity.name when ' + test.expectation, () => {
      target.entity.name = test.name;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let actual = nameElement.textContent;
        expect(actual).toEqual(test.expected);
      });
    });
  });

  [
    { expectation: 'null', type: null              , expected: null      },
    { expectation: 'set' , type: EntityType.Company, expected: 'Company' },
  ].forEach((test, i, tests) => {
    it('#type displays Entity.type when ' + test.expectation, () => {
      target.entity.type = test.type;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let actual = typeElement.value;
        expect(actual).toEqual(test.expected);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The errors I'm seeing are, summarised:

```
FAILED TESTS:
  EntityEditorComponent template
    × #type displays Entity.type when null
    Expected '' to equal null.

    × #type displays Entity.type when set
    Expected '' to equal 'Unit Test'.
```

How does the **#type displays Entity.type** test see the `Unit Test` expected value?  The only way I can see is it comes from the **#name displays Entity.name** test.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  How do I test detected changes without causing a race condition?

Comment: I think when you are using whenStable you need to wrap it in async.

Comment: Of course, it isn't possible that test.expected 'leaked' from one test to another. The specs are obviously async (there are promises) but don't have any `*async` helpers.

Comment: We're stuck using the es5 compiler which doesn't support `async` unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without plunker or code snippet, it is a little hard to investigate, however you do make tests which have an async expect run. This warrants you passing a callback to the **it()** function (by convention this is often called **done**).

Give the following a try:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EntityEditorComponent, EntityEditorModule } from '.';
import { Entity, EntityType } from '..';

describe('EntityEditorComponent template', () => {
  let target: EntityEditorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EntityEditorComponent>;
  let nameElement: HTMLInputElement;
  let typeElement: HTMLSelectElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [ EntityEditorModule ] }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntityEditorComponent);
    target = fixture.componentInstance;
    nameElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    typeElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#type')).nativeElement as HTMLSelectElement;
  });

  [
    { expectation: 'null', name: null       , expected: null        },
    { expectation: 'set' , name: 'Unit Test', expected: 'Unit Test' },
  ].forEach((test, i, tests) => {
    it('#name displays Entity.name when ' + test.expectation, done => {
      target.entity.name = test.name;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let actual = nameElement.textContent;
        expect(actual).toEqual(test.expected);
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  [
    { expectation: 'null', type: null              , expected: null      },
    { expectation: 'set' , type: EntityType.Company, expected: 'Company' },
  ].forEach((test, i, tests) => {
    it('#type displays Entity.type when ' + test.expectation, done => {
      target.entity.type = test.type;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let actual = typeElement.value;
        expect(actual).toEqual(test.expected);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```